# Trying to get property of non-object when accessing a Collection in View

Tags: php, laravel

I wrote a Controller to send Post Model along with it's Categories and Pics:

```
    class HomeController extends Controller
    {
        public function index ()
        {

            $latestPosts =
                Post::with([
                    'latestPicture',
                    'categories' => function ($query) {
                        $query->select(['categories.cat_id', 'name']);
                    }
                ])
                    ->take(12)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                    ->get(['post_id', 'post_title', 'post_alias', 'post_content', 'comments_count', 'created_at']);
//          dd($latestPosts) ;
            return view('main.pages.home', ['latestPosts' => $latestPosts]);
        }
    }
```

And for use **latestPosts** in My View I write this:

```
@if (!$latestPosts->isEmpty())
    @foreach($latestPosts as $post)
        @if( key($latestPosts) <3)
            <!-- Some HTML -->
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endif
```

but I faced this Error :

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: D:\wamp\www\TC\resources\views\main\pages\home.blade.php)
```

What is Problem? How Can I access to that Collection in the View?

Comment: You're usage is correct. Are you sure that the line causing the error is actually the one with the `@if` condition? Also the `@if` condition is not needed, because an empty collection will just not iterate anything without throwing any errors.

Comment: You could try `@if(empty($latestPosts))`

Comment: @Saad fair point, however the Query Builder's `get` method always returns a Collection instance, and even if it has no items in it, the `isEmpty` method is available nonetheless.

Comment: I think  that `@if( key($latestPosts) <3)` causing the error . because I test `{{ dd(key($latestPosts)) }}` exactly before `@if( key($latestPosts) <3)` and it return simple  `"\x00*\x00items"`.I want to get index of current Items Collection ?how can I do ?

Comment: @ahmad That's should not be the case, because there's no object property being evaluated on that line, this the error should. You should try commenting our the entire block and see if the error persists.

Comment: Also, if you want to access the collection index you can pass it in the `foreach` like so `@foreach($latestPosts as $i => $post)` and then your condition would be `@if ($i < 3)`. But if you really want to show only the first 3 elements from the collection, you can use `@foreach ($latestPosts->take(3) as $i => $post)` and remove the `@if` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that have a Typo in Accessing to Property of Post Model in My view.

I must to use **latestPicture** name instead of **latest_picture**.

I correct it and All things works fine.

Answer (score 1):

They are two things I'd rather do differently from what you have there which is likely to take away your error as you wouldn't have to use the isEmpty() property. Instead of the `@if` statement you can have a `@forelse` like:

```
@forelse($latestPosts as $key => $post)
    @if($key <= 3)
    <!-- Some HTML -->
    @endif
@empty

@endforelse
```

And should the isEmpty() property be available, I'd rather have:

```
@unless($latestPosts->isEmpty())
    @foreach()
    @endforeach
@endunless
```

instead of `@if(!$latestPosts->isEmpty())` but the latter is only about having a clearer and easier to read code. Pasting the result of `dd($latestPosts)` will make debugging a lot easier.
Even as you have corrected the typo and it took me longer to post this, I think you should consider some of the things mentioned